# No references were found in the windows sdk (Windows 1903)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, windows-10-sdk

I want to create simple toast notification to action center in windows 10 from a WPF app using [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop).

But I got problem on Step 2:

Right click on the project => Add => Reference... => Windows => Core

[image]

What I checked:

- Windows 10 SDK Installation:
  [image]
- Same issue with a WPF project

And this is my csproj file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A5A389ED-4BBB-4EF4-A8A4-45DD3D0AF9AE}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>WpfApp3</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WpfApp3</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**This error occurs after the update to Windows 1903, because Visual studio can not access C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata**

Comment: This error occurs after the update to Windows 1903, because Visual studio can not access C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio can not access the C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata directory to load the windows SDK on Windows 1903.

**So a downgrade from windows 1903 to 1803 solved this issue.**

I have reported this problem on the [visual studio developer community page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/608833/no-references-were-found-in-the-windows-sdk.html).

Answer (score 7):

On updating to the May 2019 release of Windows 10 the directory `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WinMetadata` is removed and this is where Visual Studio is 2017 and 2019 is looking for all of the files.

There is 2 way to solve this:

**1.** Click **Browse** in reference manager and chose your reference from `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WinMetadata`.

**2.** Copy **WinMetadata** folder from `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WinMetadata` to `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WinMetadata`. and then re-open reference manager.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the parent bug is documented at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/446490/visual-studio-cant-see-winmetadatadirectory-in-cwi.html

For me I clicked browse and used this path **%windir%\Sysnative\WinMetadata** and it worked for me. Windows 10 1903 \ VS 17

Comment: Jesus fkin Christ, finally. Was pulling my hair out, can't believe the hardships to add a single frikin package... Big thanks!

Comment: Additional info: adding reference from that path of yours, ended up giving me errors that compiler cannot find Windows.UI and Windows.Data files. Turns out, it is some sort of Visual Studio bug (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/446490/visual-studio-cant-see-winmetadatadirectory-in-cwi.html). As a workaround, I copied the WinMetadata folder from c:\Windows\system32 to some other accessible place and references where not throwing errors anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your issue. The node `<TargetPlatformVersion>` should be below the existing  node `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` node.

```xml
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

But there is the separate `PropertyGroup` with this node in your project file.

Comment: Same issue with a WPF project

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I updated my csproj file (see the edited question) and installed the SDK version 10.0.10240.0, but the error still exists

Comment: Even with your project file I can see these references now.

Comment: So it seems to be a visual studio bug

Comment: This error occurs after the update to Windows 1903!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 1903:

Copy WinMetadata folder from (hidden folder) C:\WINDOWS\sysnative\WinMetadata to C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WinMetadata.

Re-open reference manager.

Answer (score 0):

​The folder %windir%\Sysnative\WinMetadata does not seem to exist on my Windows 1903 (OS Build 18362.900).

My workaround was to make a local copy of the required files in %windir%\System32\WinMetadata (e.g. under a lib folder in your solution) and reference them from there.

In my case, this is how I got a hold of the Windows.Data.winmd and Windows.UI.winmd files (couldn't find them on NuGet).